# send email through php

Tags: php, html, email

First time here for me

I have 2 files (`index.html` , `sendemail.php`)

At `index.html` I have the code for my form

```
<section id="contact">
<div id="contact-us" class="parallax">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="heading text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Request a service , learn about our services</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sendemail.php">
            <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send Now</button>
            </div>
          </form>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="contact-info wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <p></p>
            <ul class="address">

              <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <span> Phone:</span> +30 6982 215487  </li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span> Email:</span><a href="mailto:info@mydomain.com"> info@mydomain.com</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span> Website:</span> <a href="#">www.mydomain.com</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>                            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At `sendemail.php` I have the code

```
 $msg = 'Name: ' .$_POST['name'] ."\n" 
.'Email :' .$_POST['email'] ."\n"
    .'Subject: ' .$_POST['subject'] ."\n"
    .'Message: ' .$_POST['message'] ."\n";
     mail('info@mydomain.com','You have one message from mydomain.com', $msg);
```

I get an email when i send this form but with no values into it like this

Name: 
Email :
Subject: 
Message:

Where is the problem with this code ?

Thanks

Comment: If you write `var_dump($_POST)` in *`sendemail.php`*, what do you see?

Comment: print $_POST and double check POST data

Comment: Maybe change the button to input, maybe better

Comment: Yes Anant , this is the code .

Comment: @kapamarou What browser are you using?

Comment: Super Cool i'm using chrome

Comment: @kapamarou  in your `sendmail.php` write `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_POST);die;` Just after `<?php`. Now save it and again refresh form and submit by filling data to it and check what output is coming.

Comment: @kapamarou Did you submit the form with nothing written in the inputs? Sounds crazy but I cannot explain if that is not the case. If not, give your test values please

Comment: Super Cool i fill the fileds with values but to email that i get the values are missing

Comment: Is the html file that much? Maybe give us a link to the page

Comment: Super Cool the page doesn't redirects to another page after form submitting.Just shows a message above the form –

Comment: Super cool santoriginal.com my domain

Comment: So, you are using XHR. You should have point out that earlier! How do you send the XHR? Through $.post?

Comment: Because the XHR is not of type POST, as detected by the network. That's why your data returns nothing, because nothing is sent to this page.

Comment: @kapamarou i will suggest you to go for normal post of form. it will easy for you.

Comment: How should i send XHR if is not the right way  ?

Comment: I am asking how you are sending the XHR!

Comment: i get the answear  from you.XHR is not type of POST. FIne.

Comment: So, problem solved?

Comment: Yes , problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

try change enctype in your form tag

```
 <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="sendemail.php">
```

also, you can print post data:

```
print(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Or, just delete the enctype

Comment: nothing happens when i change enctype. the same result

Comment: where should i print  the $_POST variables ? I work directly from  html editor to my domain

Comment: in sendmail.php, try die(print_r($_POST,true)); or die(print_r(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);

Comment: the page doesn't redirects to another page after form submitting.Just shows a message above the form

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are working on local then

   - you have to use library to send mail such as PHPMailer.
   - Check your firewall settings blocking or what.
   - Check any other service is using the ports (25,465,587).
2. If you are working on Live then

   - check your hosting provider allowing you to send mail.
     (for this you can send test mail script directly using mail function)
   - If you are using library then you have to confirm with hosting 
     provider that they allow ports opened for send mail.

Comment: He is not having problems in the server side, because the mail was successfully sent, but just with no outputs.